# How to get the value of selected checkbox in Asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I want to print the value /values of checkbox selected by the user. For that purpose I have taken a **String[] checkResp**.

**For Example:**
If checkResp[0] then select value at index 0.

View

```
<input type="checkbox" id="vehicle1" name="checkResp" value="Bike">
<label for="vehicle1"> I have a bike</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="vehicle2" name="checkResp" value="Car">
<label for="vehicle2"> I have a car</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="vehicle3" name="checkResp" value="Boat">
<label for="vehicle3"> I have a boat</label><br><br>
```

Controller

```
public ViewResult Form(string receiveremail, string subject, string message,string name, int qty, string[] checkResp) 
{
        Body = "Dear " + name +" Your Order have been successfully Placed. Number of products placed are " + qty + "from " + qty + " Store" + checkResp;
}
```

ScreenShot is attached herewith:

[image: It displays the values like this i want value at index 0]

Please if any one can help

Comment: you want to include Bike and Boat in the body text?

Comment: yes I want Bike and Boat to display  after Store in Body section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add both products use `String.Join(delimiter,array)`;

```
Body = "Dear " + name +" Your Order have been successfully Placed. Number of products placed are " + qty + "from " + qty + " Store" + String.Join(",",checkResp);
```

If you want a single item use `array[index]`;

```
Body = "Dear " + name +" Your Order have been successfully Placed. Number of products placed are " + qty + "from " + qty + " Store" + checkResp[0];
```

Comment: but  when I add checkResp[0] wouldnt  it take the value at index 0?

Comment: @Samavi use the first option in my answer then, it's `String.Join(",",checkResp)`